# I want to change or remove my html element by getting URL parameters that I set after successful register

Tags: javascript, php, html

First of all I must say that I'm very new to website design and coding so please make your answer simple thanks a lot .

So I have my file register.php that contains my form .
I have my action file named register-controller.php that gets the data from user , checks it and inserts it to database .

What I need is that whenever the register is success , my form gets hidden or removed and my new div shows up that contains 'register successful' . ( On the same page "register.php" )

Can I use the variable that I passed to header "register=success" to do this action ? Should I use AJAX ? JSON ? what should I do ? Please give me the simplest answer thank you all .

MY "register.php" file contains these :

```html
<?php 
require_once "../DB/users-database.php";
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Header.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Style.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Footer.CSS">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b3678073.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../JS/main.js" async></script>
    <title>ثبت نام | PCGA</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include '../header.php' ?>

<div class="register-container">
    <form action="../controllers/register-controller.php" method = "POST">
        <label class = "email-label" for="email">ایمیل</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" value = '<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){echo $_REQUEST['email'];}else{echo '';} ?>'>
        <?php 
        if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'emptyEmail'){
            echo "<span class = 'empty-email'>فیلد نباید خالی باشد *</span>";
        }
        else if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'invalidEmailFormat') {
            echo "<span class = 'formaterr-email'>فرمت ایمیل نادرست است*</span>";
        }
        ?>
        <label class = "phone-label" for="phone">شماره موبایل</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="09xxxxxxxxx" value = '<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['phone'])){echo $_REQUEST['phone'];}else{echo '';} ?>'>
        <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'emptyPhone'){
            echo "<span class = 'empty-phone'>فیلد نباید خالی باشد *</span>";
        }
        else if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'invalidPhoneNumber') {
            echo "<span class = 'formaterr-phone'>شماره موبایل حداکثر 11 عدد است و حروف قابل قبول نیست*</span>";
        }
        ?>
        <label class = "user-label" for="username">نام کاربری</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value = '<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])){echo $_REQUEST['username'];}else{echo '';} ?>'>
        <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'emptyUsername'){
            echo "<span class = 'empty-user'>فیلد نباید خالی باشد *</span>";
        }
        else if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'invalidUserName') {
            echo "<span class = 'formaterr-user'>فرمت نام کابری نادرست است*</span>";
        }
        ?>
        <label class="pass-label" for="password">رمز عبور</label>
        <input type="password" id = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "Password" >
        <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['error']) && $_REQUEST['error'] == 'emptyPass'){
            echo "<span class = 'empty-pass'>فیلد نباید خالی باشد *</span>";
        }
        ?>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
            <input type="checkbox" class = 'checkbox-style' name = 'rules-check'>
            <label for="checkbox" class="checkbox-label">من قوانین فروشگاه را کامل مطالعه کرده ام و با آن موافق هستم</label>
            <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['rules'])){
            echo "<span class = 'rules-error'>قبول قوانین اجباری است و آن را حتما مطالعه کنید *</span>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name = "submit" id="submit">ثبت نام</button>
    </form>
</div>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['register'])){
    echo "<div class = 'register-success'>
    <span class = 'register-success-span'>ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد</span>
</div>" ;
}

?>

<?php include '../footer.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

MY "register-controller.php" file contains these :

```html
<?php 
require "../DB/users-database.php";

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['rules-check']) {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);

    if (empty($username)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=emptyUsername&username=".$username."&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (empty($phone)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=emptyPhone&username=".$username."&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (empty($pass)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=emptyPass&username=".$username."&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (empty($email)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=emptyEmail&username=".$username."&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=invalidEmailFormat&username=".$username."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-z\d_]{2,20}$/i" , $username)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=invalidUserName&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{11}+$/" , $phone)){
        header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=invalidPhoneNumber&email=".$username."&phone=".$phone);
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM registered WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $sql)){
            header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=SQLcheckUser");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , "s" , $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $rowcount = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if($rowcount > 0 ) {
                header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=UserNameTaken");
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO registered(email,phone,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $sql)){
                    header("Location: ../page/register.php?error=SQLInsert");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $hased_pass = password_hash($pass , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , "ssss" , $email , $phone , $username , $hased_pass);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../page/register.php?register=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_POST['rules-check'])) {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    header("Location: ../page/register.php?rules=notChecked&username=".$username."&email=".$email."&phone=".$phone);
    exit();
}
else {
    header("Location: ../page/register.php?access=denied");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the part of the page you prefer depending on your URL parameters by doing

```php
<?php
if ($_GET['success']) { ?>

   <-- YOUR HTML SUCCESS CODE -->

<?php } else { ?>

   <-- YOUR HTML FORM CODE -->

<?php }
?>
```

Comment: THANKS !!! BEST ANSWER . Useful and short . You are the best . Sorry I can't vote up because I'm new to stackoverflow .

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the best solution for me (it can be difficult to understand but the code is clean), here an example of Ajax with your situation :
`Extras` is the ID of all the input in the form
`Page` is the PHP page to be executed (register-controller.php)
`Origin` is the ID where you want to put the result, *`Origin` can be `null`*.
(To have something in the return, you have to put an `echo` in the php file you specified in `Page`)

```
static Ajax(origin,Extras,page)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = new FormData();
    
    for(var element in Extras)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(element))
        {
           formData.append(element,document.getElementById(element));
        }
        else
        {
          let checkbox = document.getElementsByName(element);
          if(checkbox)
          {
             //Checkbox don't work with an ID so put instead a name
             for(let i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++)
             {
                if(checkbox[i].checked)
                {                    
                   formdata.append(element+i,"1")
                }
                else
                {
                   formdata.append(element+i,"0")
                }
             }
          }
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST',page);

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {

        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            let i= xhr.responseText;
            if(origin!=null)
            {
                if(document.getElementById(origin) && xhr.responseText!="")
                 // the result   document.getElementById(origin).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
            finish(i);
        }
        else if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status != 200) {
            // error message XHR,
            let textError = "Ajax Error : " + xhr.status + ", " + xhr.statusText + ", ";
            alert(textError);
        }

    });

    // send
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: This is actually complicated but very useful for me because I'm new and I should learn AJAX. This situation maybe easier with php but I will face lots of other situations later in my coding that need AJAX . Thanks a lot for your answer useful ! Sorry I can't vote up because I'm new to stackoverflow .